# Total derivative question

Tags: derivatives

Here is what I'm confused about. Imagine we have a function $U(x_1,y_1,z_1,x_2,y_2,z_2)$ and we want to calculate the derivative of this function with respect to another variable $R$ which is a function of $x_1,y_1,z_1,x_2,y_2,z_2$:
\begin{equation}
R=R(x_1,y_1,z_1,x_2,y_2,z_2)=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2+(z_2-z_1)^2}
\end{equation}
What is the derivative $\dfrac{dU}{dR}$ and is it defined at all? I thought that the answer is given simply by applying a chain rule:
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{dU}{dR}=\sum\limits_{i=1,2}\sum\limits_{\xi=x,y,z}\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial \xi_i}\dfrac{\partial \xi_i}{\partial R}
\end{equation}
In this case the answer would be (inverting Equation for R):
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{dU}{dR}=\sum\limits_{i=1,2}\sum\limits_{\xi=x,y,z}\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial \xi_i}\left(\dfrac{\partial R}{\partial \xi_i}\right)^{-1}
\end{equation}
Yet somehow I feel that it is a wrong answer because it is impossible to imagine a consistent finite difference analog for this derivative.

What am I doing wrong and is it possible that $\dfrac{dU}{dR}$ is not well defined?

Comment: What does it mean to compute the derivative of a function with respect to another function?

Answer (score 0):

It is most definitely the wrong answer. You are playing fast and loose with the partial derivative notation, pretending it should behave just like a normal derivative. But there are very important reasons why partial derivatives are called "partial" and are always expressed with that funky $\partial$ symbol  instead of the normal $d$.

For example, suppose I have a function $f$ assigning real numbers to the points on the plane. Now I can choose some coordinate system, identifying those points with ordered pairs of values $(x, y)$. Now under this assignment, I find that I can express my function as $f(x, y) = y - x$. But I can also define $u = x + y$, which allows me to express $f(u, y) = y - (u - y) = 2y - u$.

Note that in the $(x, y)$ coordinate system, $$\frac {\partial f}{\partial y} = 1$$ but in the $(u, y)$ coordinate system, $$\frac {\partial f}{\partial y} = 2$$
even though it is the same $y$ in both: The other coordinate changed, not $y$.

Partial derivatives depend not just on the variable the differentiation is respect to, but on the entire collection of variables on which the function depends.

And this is the downfall of your analysis. ${\dfrac {\partial R}{\partial \xi_i}}$ is well defined, but what does ${\dfrac {\partial \xi_i}{\partial R}}$ mean? This requires $\xi_i$ to be a function of $R$ and some other values. What are the other values? That value of the partial derivative depends upon the choice you make.

(Your abuse of notation by treating $\xi$ as an index for letters makes this impossible to describe properly, so instead I'm treating $\xi_i$ as a normal indexed variable with $i$ running from $1$ to $6$ and $\xi$ just being a fixed letter. You can pick how those six indices align with $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2, z_1, z_2$ yourself.)

Of couse, you can just say $\xi_i$ is a function of $R$ and the other $\xi_j, j \ne i$. If you were discussing ${\dfrac {\partial \xi_i}{\partial R}}$ in isolation, this would be acceptable. But you aren't. You are using it in coordination with ${\dfrac {\partial \xi_j}{\partial R}}$ for each of the other $j$. In the latter $\xi_j$ is a function of $R$ and $\xi_i$, but you also have $\xi_i$ is a function of $\xi_j$ at the same time, which becomes meaningless. You cannot have $\xi_i$ and $\xi_j$ as dependent variables of each other at the same time.